# Javascript character limit counter function for text input

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I've made a counter with javascript that shows a user how characters are remaining (from a set limit) for some text input or text area. Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function CountRemaining()
{
    var limit = 1000;
    var count = document.getElementById('press-form-body').value.length;
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = ((limit-count) + " characters left");
    var timer = setTimeout("CountRemaining()",50);
}
</script>
```

My abomination above works fine but my problem is that I need to use this multiple times and making a separate function for every time I need it would be impractical to say the least.

I tried this and it didn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function CountRemaining(string, targetcounter, limit)
{
    var count = document.getElementById(string).value.length;
    document.getElementById(targetcounter).innerHTML = ((limit-count) + " characters left");
    var timer = setTimeout("CountRemaining()",50);
}
```

I then figured I put the wrong statement for the timer so I changed it to this but still didn't work:

```
var timer = setTimeout("CountRemaining(string, targetcounter, limit)",50);
```

I'm lost. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: amchang87 is putting you on the right path below, this would be better suited to an event.  Though as an aside, your setTimeout problem can be solved with this common pattern: `setTimeout(function(){ CountRemaining(string, targetcounter, limit); },50);`

Comment: @DanielMendel - You're awesome! That's EXACTLY what I needed! Now that it works and I'm not feeling guilty anymore, I'll modify it to use amchang87's solution instead of the timer since it only runs when it's needed. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

I think a better idea would be to use the "onchange" event for those types of elements.

Basically as soon as the text area / text input loses focus and is changed, you can bind a function to count how many characters are left.

```
document.getElementById('press-form-body').onchange = function() {
 // your stuff (double check this to make sure the "this" value is right
  // use this as an example
  document.getElementById(targetcounter).innerHTML = this.value.length - 1000
}
```

Another solution would be to use the "key" events to listen to any keypress in the inputs.

```
 document.getElementById('press-form-body').onkeypress = function() {
     // your stuff (double check this to make sure the "this" value is right
      // use this as an example
      document.getElementById(targetcounter).innerHTML = this.value.length - 1000
    }
```

Comment: I'm not good with javascript but I think I know where you're going with this and I like it! I'll try it out now. Thanks!

Comment: Onchange events are dispatched when the element loses focus (except for some browsers and radio buttons, checkboxes and option elements), so not suitable for tracking characters left while typing.

Comment: An better idea would be to use the `input` event, falling back to `change` or `keyup` if it’s not supported: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/oninput

Answer (score 0):

```
function limittxt()
{
    var tval = document.getElementById('press-form-body').value;
    tlength = tval.length;
    set = 100;
    remain = parseInt(set - tlength);
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = remain + " characters left";
    if (remain <= 0) {
    document.getElementById('press-form-body').value = tval.substring(0, tlength - Math.abs(remain)))
    }
}
```

An call this function in the input element like the following :

```
<input type='text' onkeypress='limittxt()' onkeyup='limittxt()' onkeydown='limittxt()'>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the error is with following line:

```
var timer = setTimeout("CountRemaining(string, targetcounter, limit)",50);
```

Here i think it should come like:

```
var str = "CountRemaining(" + string + "," + targetcounter + "," + limit + ")";
var timer = setTimeout(str,50);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to proceed along the lines of using the timer to run the function at regular intervals, then you would need code similar to the following (hat-tip to @Sameera Thilakasiri for the inspiration):

```
function CountRemaining(string, targetcounter, limit){
    var count = document.getElementById(string).value.length;
    document.getElementById(targetcounter).innerHTML = ((limit-count) + " characters left");
}

setInterval(function() {
    // call the function for each of the inputs on the page you need a counter for
    CountRemaining('press-form-body', 'counter', 1000);
    // etc
}, 50);
```

However, I believe @amchang87's approach is better overall, so I recommend you go with that if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Tracking the number of characters left is always a little difficult. A good event to use is keyup or keypress, but that doesn't cover text that is dragged and dropped into the element, so people end up using a timer.

If you have many elements to monitor, consider putting them into an array, then call the timer at each interval and check all of the elements. Be careful with performance though, running the function every 50 ms may sap quite a bit of browser performance so try to keep the processing to an absolute minimum.

That means caching whatever you can and keep the logic simple.

#### Edit

The `run` and `stop` methods below could be used to start the timer when particular elements get focus, then stop it when they lose focus. That way you aren't hogging resources when not required.

#### /Edit

```
var keyCountCheck = (function() {
  var elementArray, timerRef;
  return {

    // Initialise once
    init: function() {
      var input, inputs;

      // Initialise elementArray if hasn't been done already
      // If adding and removing elements, create new aray
      // instead each time.
      if (!elementArray) {
        elementArray = [];
        inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

        for (var i=0, iLen=inputs.length; i<iLen; i++) {
          input = inputs[i];

          if (input.type == 'text') {
            elementArray.push(input);
          }
        }
      }
      timerRef = window.setInterval(keyCountCheck.run, 50);
    },

    // Run timer
    run: function() {

      // If setInterval not running, start it
      if (!timerRef) {
        keyCountCheck.init();
      }
      var el;

      for (var i=0, iLen=elementArray.length; i<iLen; i++) {
        checkLength(elementArray[i]);
      }
    },

    // In case there is a reason to stop this thing.         
    stop: function() {
      if (timerRef) {
        window.clearTimeout(timerRef);
        timerRef = null;
      }
    }
  };
}());

window.onload = keyCountCheck.init;


function checkLength(el) {


  // Character limit can be set as a data- attribute or
  // class or various other ways. This is the simple way
  var limit = 10;
  var msgEl = document.getElementById(el.id + '_limitMsg');

  if (msgEl) {
    msgEl.innerHTML = (limit - el.value.length) + ' characters left. ' + (new Date()); 
  }
}
```

Some supporting HTML to play with:

```
<input id="i0" value="1"><span id="i0_limitMsg"></span>
<br>
<input id="i1" value="2"><span id="i1_limitMsg"></span>

<br>
<button onclick="keyCountCheck.stop()">stop</button>
<button onclick="keyCountCheck.run()">run</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
setInterval(
  function CountRemaining(string, targetcounter, limit){
    var count = document.getElementById(string).value.length;
    document.getElementById(targetcounter).innerHTML = ((limit-count) + " characters left");
  },50
);
```

Tryout this way.

Basic concept of this solution,

```
var   f = function() {function_name(arg1); };
setTimeout(f, msec);
```

Comment: This would only run it once, as it does not call `setTimeout()` again. This approach might work with `setInterval()`, though.

Comment: So, I can change setTimeout to setInterval same example?

Comment: Actually, on looking at it, that won't work, because you are not correctly passing the values for the 3 parameters the function needs each time.

Comment: What you mean by correctly not passing values? could you please correct the answer?

Comment: I'll create a new answer that illustrates how I think a solution along these lines would work.